# ActiveXObject is not invoked in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, html, windows, batch-file, activex

I'm executing a batch file from JS (client side). It's working in Windows 7 and 8, but in Windows 10 there's no activity: the ActiveXObject object is not invoked.

I need some input. Is there a better/another way to do this?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
            function Runbat()
            {
                MyObject.Run("\"C:\\test.bat\"");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Run a Program</h1>
        This script launch the file any bat File<p>
        <button onclick="Runbat()">Run bat File</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ActiveX objects are no longer supported by default in MS Edge. You can try enabling them again by following one of the several guides you can find on google, but best would be to find a proper replacement for the functionality if you want a secure site.

Comment: If you're only trying to run a local bat file, you can try playing around with `window.open( 'file:///C:/test.bat' )`, but that might still ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run this in IE11 or Edge? It certainly won't work in Edge. It may work on IE if you have your security settings set appropriately to run active content.

If that doesn't work, you would need to change your HTML file into a HTA file instead. This is assuming you are opening the file directly rather than hosting it on a local web server.